# How to extract the last four letters from the DOB field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the Generate username button to to generate a username which will be forename+username+year_of_birth.

I am able to concatenate both forename and surname, however how do i only extract (and concatenate) the last four letters(or numbers, actually) ?

```
<p>First name:  <input type="text" id="fname" /></p>
<p>Surname: <input type="text" id="sname" /></p>
<p>Date of birth:   <input type="text" id="dob" /> (Please enter as dd/mm/yyyy)</p>
<button onclick="user()">Generate Username</button>
    <p id="username"></p>

    <script>

        function user()
        {
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("fname").value+document.getElementById("sname").value+document.getElementById("dob").value

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: you have to extract complete but then can use substring or other string method to split the string

Comment: You can use `<input type="date" />` rather than text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Using the correct `input type` will make your web more robust. Also, you should do some data validation before using those fields. What should happen when users do not enter anything but click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice the dob if its length is > 4 from forth last element to last element

```js
function user() {
   
  var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var sName = document.getElementById("sname").value;
  var dob =  document.getElementById("dob").value
  if(dob.length > 4 )
  var dob = dob.slice(dob.length - 4, dob.length);
  
  document.getElementById("username").innerHTML =fName+sName+dob

}
```

```html
<p>First name: <input type="text" id="fname" /></p>
<p>Surname: <input type="text" id="sname" /></p>
<p>Date of birth: <input type="text" id="dob" /> (Please enter as dd/mm/yyyy)</p>
<button onclick="user()">Generate Username</button>
<p id="username"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("dob").value.slice(-4)
```